# erlang:is_port/1 and sockets

Tags: erlang

I was reading more about `erlang:is_port/1` so I decided to test it with several values.

I saw that with normal sockets it replies `true` if the socket is up and `false` otherwise (i.e. socket is down).

Can `is_port/1` be used also with ssl sockets? I tried but it always returns `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to a *SSL Socket* as the returned value from (for example) `ssl:connect/2,3`, then the answer is "no". The SSL Sockets in the context of the SSL application are of a `sslsocket()` type, which, [according to the documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html) are opaque to the user and definitely not a port. Specifically, they are records:

```
%% Looks like it does for backwards compatibility reasons
-record(sslsocket, {fd = nil, pid = nil}).
```